# Django dynamic page functionality and url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a some problem with routing in my django app.

**The problem:** 
There is some dynamic website and site administrator can create pages with random urls. For example, he can create a news page with url "company/news" or "store/news". Or he can create the page with feedback form with url "feedback" or "user/feedback".

So, Django needs to catch this request and show appropriate news or feedback content for these pages. How can I route the user request to the appropriate view according to the requested page functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create view that parses your URL and chooses strategy for different types.

```
# urls.py
...
url(r'^dynamic-view/(?P<dynamic_view_url>.*)/$', 'dynamic_view')


# views.py
def dynamic_view(request, dynamic_view_url):
    url_parts = [p for p in dynamic_view_url.split("/") if p]
    if "feedback" in url_parts:
        return _view_for_feedback(request, url_parts)
    elif "news" in url_parts:
        return _view_for_news(request, url_parts)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've found the another solution. I get all pages urls from my database and dynamically assign url rules in my url configuration:modules = PageHelpers().get_available_modules()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'app.home.views.index'),
    *(('^%s/'%mod['url'], include('app.%s.urls'%mod['module_char_id'])) for mod in modules)

) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Do you restart django if database changes and you need new version of urlpatterns?

Comment: Yes, with this approach you need to restart your app each time when url schema in database is changing. Actually, I'm not using this approach now, Django is not about dynamic URLs.